# remove special word woocommerce products title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove special word woocommerce products title

Example:

```
Products title: vidaXL Dining Chairs 2 pcs Solid Acacia Wood Sheesham
```

So, I want to remove `vidaXL` from WooCommerce website. This website still, 18000 products available so manually is not possible. If possible then please any WooCommerce functions.

I already tried so please someone help me.

Comment: If it is always the same word you have to remove (vidaXL), it will be easy to find and replace it in your database or with an import/export product plugin and modifications in a Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'theme_change_field_names', 20, 3 );
function theme_change_field_names( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {



        switch ( $translated_text ) {

            case 'vidaXL' :

                $translated_text = __( '', 'theme_text_domain' );
                break;


        }



    return $translated_text;
}
```